# skoda el-mir theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

now i'm studying the skoda el-mir theorem about the extension of a positive closed current $T$.
But if $T$ ed $S$ are two positive closed currents on a manifold $X$ such that are equal on $X\setminus A$ where $A$ is an analytic set of $X$ then is it true that $S=T$ on whole $X$? 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take for example $T=0$ and $S=[A]$ the current of integration over a closed complex analytic hypersurface $A$.